# Finding a suitable comparison p-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying calculus, namely series and their convergence, and I'm stumped with this exercise.

Given

$$\sum_{n\ge1}a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k}$$

I'm supposed to find $k$ such the series is convergent. The convergence of $a_n$ can be determined by comparison with an appropriate p-series, which I believe to be $\sum_{n\ge1}b_n = \frac{n^{1/2}}{n^k} = \frac{1}{n^{(k-1/2)}}$.

The obvious issue is I can't show that $a_n \le b_n$ for all $n$, on the contrary. But if I have chosen the correct p-series for comparison, then how is it so?

I have seen other related questions had answers relying on asymptotic analysis, by noting that $\sqrt{n+1} \sim_{\infty} \sqrt{n}$, but I was looking for a more formal way to come up with a sequence $b_n$ that bounds $a_n$ from above and that can be written as a p-series.

Comment: One approach I've tried which seemed to have worked is to note that $\sqrt{n+1} \le \sqrt{n}+1$ for all $n$ and go from there. Is that viable?

Comment: Since $\sqrt{n} < \sqrt{n+1} \le \sqrt{n+n} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}$, then $n^{1/2-k}  < \sqrt{n+1}/n^k \le \sqrt{2} n^{1/2 - k}$. So by direct comparison it suffices to find $k$ such that $\sum n^{1/2-k}$ converges.

Comment: Also, you should not write $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n = \frac{n+1}{n^k}$, but $a_n = \frac{n+1}{n^k}$, since you are interested in the series $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k}$.

Comment: "$\sum_{n\ge1}a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k}$" is a [splice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run-on_sentence) jamming the two sentences "study this sum" and "the general terms are this" together ungrammatically.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @kobe!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways to proceed.  Here are a few.

### Pull out the big part

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k} &= \frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{n^k}  \\
    &= \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{n^{k-1/2}} 
\end{align*}
Now realize the numerator satisfies $1 \leq \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \leq 2$ for all $n \geq 1$.  (This can be sharpened to $1 < \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \leq \sqrt{2}$, but such sharpness does not improve the result or readability.)  So
$$  \frac{1}{n^{k-1/2}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k} \leq \frac{2}{n^{k-1/2}}  $$
Then use what you know about $p$-series (and constant multiples) to resolve the convergence of the given series using the first and third expressions as terms.

### Clear the radical

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k} &= \frac{n+1}{n^k\sqrt{n+1}}  \\
    &= \frac{n}{n^k\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{n^k\sqrt{n+1}}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{n^{k-1}\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{n^k\sqrt{n+1}}  \\
    &< \frac{1}{n^{k-1}\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n^k\sqrt{n+1}}  &  \left[n + 1 > n, \text{ so } \sqrt{n + 1} > \sqrt{n}, \text{ so } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right]  \\
    &< \frac{1}{n^{k-1}\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n^k\sqrt{n}}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{n^{k-1/2}} + \frac{1}{n^{k+1/2}}  \\
\end{align*}
The use what you know about $p$-series to determine the constraints on $k$ so that each series using one of the two terms in the last row converges.  Take the intersection of those constraints to find when the original series converges.  This method is somewhat unsatisfactory because the two strict inequalities *could* indicate that convergence is possible with even smaller $k$s.  That doesn't happen this time.  (The bounding inequalities in the first method are one way to see that the "gap" introduced by the strict inequalities here do not allow a change as large as altering $k$.)

### Sneaky identity

Note that $\sqrt{n+1} \leq \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{n} + 1$ for $n \geq 1$.  One way to show this is that the square root function is monotonically increasing and the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ with respect to $x$ satisfies, for $x \geq 1$,  \begin{align*}
x &\geq 1  \\
\sqrt{x} &\geq \sqrt{1} = 1  \\
2\sqrt{x} &\geq 2  \\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} &\leq \frac{1}{2}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Now suppose $\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n} + 1$.  Then, \begin{align*}
\sqrt{n+1} &> \sqrt{n} + 1  \\
\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n} &> 1  \\
\frac{\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}}{1} &> 1  \\
\frac{\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)-n} &> 1  \\
\end{align*}But the mean value theorem requires a point $c \in (n,n+1)$ such that $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}} > 1$, which we have already shown cannot happen for $c > n \geq 1$.  This establishes the inequality in the first line of this section.

Then, \begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k} &\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1}}{n^k}  \\
    &= \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n^k}  \\
    &= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^k} + \frac{1}{n^k}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Then apply what you know about $p$-series to the series made from each of the terms in the last row.  The intersection of the resulting requirements on $k$ produce the desired outcome.  Similar to the previous method, the "gap", $\sqrt{n} + 1 - \sqrt{n+1}$, is a little unsatisfying, but inequalities similar to the one in the first solution show that this gap is not large enough to alter $k$.

### Change the index

... to make the numerator simple.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^k} &= \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)^k}  \\
    &= \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^k \left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right) ^k}  \\
    &= \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^{k-1/2} \left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right) ^k}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
Then, analogous to the first method, \begin{align*}
2 &\leq n < \infty  \\
\frac{1}{2} &\geq \frac{1}{n} > 0  \\
-\frac{1}{2} &\leq -\frac{1}{n} < 0  \\
1-\frac{1}{2} &\leq 1-\frac{1}{n} < 1  \\
\frac{1}{2} &\leq 1-\frac{1}{n} < 1  \\
\frac{1}{2^k} &\leq \left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right) ^k < 1  \\
2^k &\geq \frac{1}{\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right) ^k} > 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So
$$ 2^k \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^{k-1/2}} \geq \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{k}} > \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^{k-1/2}}  \text{.}  $$
Now apply what you know about $p$-series to resolve the first and third of these, which justifies pulling the constant out of the first one when $k$ is such that the series in the first one converges.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Eric, I really appreciate you posting different approaches to reach a conclusion!